# JBoss 7.1.1 + mod_cluster : Session replication - Can't find resource org.jboss.as.web.session.LocalStrings

Tags: jboss, mod-cluster

I am running JBoss 7.1.1 instances and `httpd` + `mod_cluster` in the standalone mode

Machine1: JBoss 7.1.1 , Apache `httpd` + `mod_cluster` (windows 7)

Machine2 : JBoss 7.1.1 (windows 7)

I am starting the nodes in with the below command

```
standalone -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.168.4.76 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.server.base.dir=../standalonenode1 -Djboss.node.name=node1

standalone -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.168.4.81 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.server.base.dir=../standalonenode2 -Djboss.node.name=node2
```

Apache httpd is installed as a service,configured with JBoss mod cluster subsystem.

I have written a sample application to test the session replication. When the node1 is down, the session object becomes null. The following contents are from server.log file,

```
22:36:23,111 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies] (ajp--192.168.4.81-9595-1) Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=yzC5kdQ1jre0T2FnNhVAI6J6.standalonenode1

22:36:23,134 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.util.StringManager] (ajp--192.168.4.81-9595-1) Can't find resource org.jboss.as.web.session.LocalStrings ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.sampleSession-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader
```

The above setup is completely working fine in a remote environment(windows 2012) and i tried to set it up locally with windows 7 machines.

I opened up `jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar` and there is no class file with the name `org.jboss.as.web.session.LocalStrings`.

Please help.

Thanks

Venkat

Comment: How are you doing to stop the node?

Comment: I am just using CTRL + C to stop the JBoss instance.

Comment: The graceful shutdown of a node will not result in a failover. Try kill the process, eg use task manager to end process execution.

Comment: But after providing CTRL +C itself, the process is not available in task manager. In the second iteration, i had seen the "java.exe" process is getting terminated in Task Manager.

Comment: CTRL+C signal is captured by jboss and generate graceful shutdown and session is drained. To test session failover you need kill the process.